# Cordova Activity is being re-launched on its own

Tags: android, cordova, motorola

I have a native Android app where I have only one activity (MainActivity). In my app I've imported a module where I have another activities. So in my app's main activity onResume() method I'm calling to another class method (that is inside the imported module) where I'm starting a second activity that is a subclass of CordovaActivity.
The cordova activity is shown correctly, the problem is that every now and then the activity is relaunched, this is that the onDestroy() is called and right after, the onCreate() is called. This is happening only using a Motorola Droid Maxx with Android version 4.4.4.

Do you know why could be this happening? And how could I solve it?

**EDIT:**
This is the log before and after the activity was relaunched.

> 02-22 18:01:33.138 22004-22389/com.healthchat.healthchat I/opentok-session: Session is connected
>   02-22 18:01:33.138 22004-22389/com.healthchat.healthchat I/opentok-session: New session connection is created. ConnectionId: 8b0ee595-a97a-48c4-8538-6404ef7e92b7
>   02-22 18:01:33.139 22004-22432/com.healthchat.healthchat I/QCNEA   : |NIMS|: getaddrinfo: hostname hlg.tokbox.com servname 443 numeric 0 appname /system/bin/app_process
>   02-22 18:01:33.140 22004-22004/com.healthchat.healthchat I/OTPlugin: session connected, triggering sessionConnected Event. My Cid is: 8546EDAC-E218-4523-8CD5-897ED95D3F39
>   02-22 18:01:33.141 22004-22004/com.healthchat.healthchat I/OTPlugin: connectionCreated
>   02-22 18:01:33.150 22004-22004/com.healthchat.healthchat I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(290)] "JS Lib: session event received - ", source: file:///android_asset/framework_assets/plugins/com.tokbox.cordova.opentok/www/opentok.js (290)
>   02-22 18:01:33.150 22004-22004/com.healthchat.healthchat I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(290)] "JS Lib: sessionConnectedHandler - ", source: file:///android_asset/framework_assets/plugins/com.tokbox.cordova.opentok/www/opentok.js (290)
>   02-22 18:01:33.151 22004-22004/com.healthchat.healthchat I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(290)] "JS Lib: session event received - ", source: file:///android_asset/framework_assets/plugins/com.tokbox.cordova.opentok/www/opentok.js (290)
>   02-22 18:01:33.157 22004-22004/com.healthchat.healthchat I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Connected to Coordination Room:", source: file:///android_asset/framework_assets/app.js (1)
>   02-22 18:01:33.369 22004-22004/com.healthchat.healthchat I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "2. settingRecipientInfo", source: file:///android_asset/framework_assets/app.js (1)
>   02-22 18:01:35.846 22004-22241/com.healthchat.healthchat D/Pushwoosh: [NotificationPrefs] get cached tags: {userId=14951}
>   02-22 18:01:35.846 22004-22241/com.healthchat.healthchat D/Pushwoosh: [NotificationPrefs] update cached tags: {userId=14951}
>   02-22 18:01:35.855 22004-22004/com.healthchat.healthchat I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Settings track", source: file:///android_asset/framework_assets/app.js (1)
>   02-22 18:01:36.843 22004-22029/com.healthchat.healthchat D/Pushwoosh: [RequestManager] Try To send: setTags
>   02-22 18:01:37.056 22004-22029/com.healthchat.healthchat I/Pushwoosh: [RequestManager] 
>                                                                         x
>                                                                         |     Pushwoosh request:
>                                                                         | 
>                                                                         | Payload: {"request":{"tags":{"userId":"14951"},"v":"4.1.5","application":"DBCD2-4E3E5","hwid":"75e1bbb1ee4980df","device_type":3,"userId":"75e1bbb1ee4980df"}}
>                                                                         | Response: {"status_code":200,"status_message":"OK","response":{"skipped":[]}}
>                                                                         x
>   02-22 18:01:37.056 22004-22029/com.healthchat.healthchat D/Pushwoosh: [RequestManager] setTags response success
>   02-22 18:01:37.057 22004-22004/com.healthchat.healthchat W/[[--TEST PUSH--]]: Tags success: {}
>   02-22 18:01:37.364 22004-22004/com.healthchat.healthchat E/Camera: Error 5001
>   02-22 18:01:37.374 22004-22004/com.healthchat.healthchat I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "CAMERA SHOWWW before!!!", source: file:///android_asset/framework_assets/app.js (1)
>   02-22 18:01:37.404 22004-22004/com.healthchat.healthchat I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "recipientInfo", source: file:///android_asset/framework_assets/app.js (1)
>   02-22 18:01:37.405 22004-22004/com.healthchat.healthchat I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "not undefined!!", source: file:///android_asset/framework_assets/app.js (1)
>   02-22 18:01:37.448 22004-22004/com.healthchat.healthchat I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "list activate!!!", source: file:///android_asset/framework_assets/app.js (1)
>   02-22 18:01:37.508 22004-22004/com.healthchat.healthchat I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "activateeee!!!>...", source: file:///android_asset/framework_assets/app.js (1)
>   02-22 18:01:37.509 22004-22004/com.healthchat.healthchat I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "CAMERA SHOWWW before!!!", source: file:///android_asset/framework_assets/app.js (1)
>   02-22 18:01:37.514 22004-22004/com.healthchat.healthchat I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "CAMERA SHOWWW!!!", source: file:///android_asset/framework_assets/app.js (1)
>   02-22 18:01:37.802 22004-22004/com.healthchat.healthchat I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Camera view track", source: file:///android_asset/framework_assets/app.js (1)
>   02-22 18:01:37.810 22004-22004/com.healthchat.healthchat I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "recipientInfo", source: file:///android_asset/framework_assets/app.js (1)
>   02-22 18:01:37.811 22004-22004/com.healthchat.healthchat I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "not undefined!!", source: file:///android_asset/framework_assets/app.js (1)
>   02-22 18:01:37.825 22004-22004/com.healthchat.healthchat I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "recipient name", source: file:///android_asset/framework_assets/app.js (1)
>   02-22 18:01:38.256 22004-22004/com.healthchat.healthchat I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(25)] "No Content-Security-Policy meta tag found. Please add one when using the cordova-plugin-whitelist plugin.", source: file:///android_asset/framework_assets/plugins/cordova-plugin-whitelist/whitelist.js (25)
>   02-22 18:01:38.508 22004-22004/com.healthchat.healthchat I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "CAMERA SHOWWW before!!!", source: file:///android_asset/framework_assets/app.js (1)
>   02-22 18:01:38.508 22004-22004/com.healthchat.healthchat I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "CAMERA SHOWWW!!!", source: file:///android_asset/framework_assets/app.js (1)
>   02-22 18:01:38.550 22004-22004/com.healthchat.healthchat I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Camera view track", source: file:///android_asset/framework_assets/app.js (1)
>   02-22 18:01:38.557 22004-22004/com.healthchat.healthchat I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "activateeee!!!>...", source: file:///android_asset/framework_assets/app.js (1)
>   02-22 18:01:38.557 22004-22004/com.healthchat.healthchat I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "CAMERA SHOWWW before!!!", source: file:///android_asset/framework_assets/app.js (1)
>   02-22 18:01:38.558 22004-22004/com.healthchat.healthchat I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "CAMERA SHOWWW!!!", source: file:///android_asset/framework_assets/app.js (1)
>   02-22 18:01:38.564 22004-22004/com.healthchat.healthchat I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Camera view track", source: file:///android_asset/framework_assets/app.js (1)
>   02-22 18:01:39.299 22004-22004/com.healthchat.healthchat I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "ONLINE? ", source: file:///android_asset/framework_assets/app.js (1)
>   02-22 18:01:39.301 22004-22004/com.healthchat.healthchat I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "max", source: file:///android_asset/framework_assets/app.js (1)
>   02-22 18:01:39.302 22004-22004/com.healthchat.healthchat I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "inbox", source: file:///android_asset/framework_assets/app.js (1)
>   02-22 18:01:39.304 22004-22241/com.healthchat.healthchat D/Pushwoosh: [ShortcutBadger] Finding badger
>   02-22 18:01:39.307 22004-22241/com.healthchat.healthchat E/Pushwoosh: [ShortcutBadger] Returning badger:com.pushwoosh.thirdparty.shortcutbadger.impl.DefaultBadger
>   02-22 18:01:39.861 22004-22004/com.healthchat.healthchat I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "max", source: file:///android_asset/framework_assets/app.js (1)
>   02-22 18:01:39.863 22004-22004/com.healthchat.healthchat I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "inbox", source: file:///android_asset/framework_assets/app.js (1)
>   02-22 18:01:39.871 22004-22004/com.healthchat.healthchat I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "max", source: file:///android_asset/framework_assets/app.js (1)
>   02-22 18:01:39.872 22004-22004/com.healthchat.healthchat I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "inbox", source: file:///android_asset/framework_assets/app.js (1)
>   02-22 18:01:40.310 22004-22029/com.healthchat.healthchat D/Pushwoosh: [RequestManager] Try To send: setBadge
>   02-22 18:01:40.521 22004-22029/com.healthchat.healthchat I/Pushwoosh: [RequestManager] 
>                                                                         x
>                                                                         |     Pushwoosh request:
>                                                                         | 
>                                                                         | Payload: {"request":{"v":"4.1.5","application":"DBCD2-4E3E5","badge":12,"hwid":"75e1bbb1ee4980df","device_type":3,"userId":"75e1bbb1ee4980df"}}
>                                                                         | Response: {"status_code":200,"status_message":"OK","response":null}
>                                                                         x
>   02-22 18:01:40.521 22004-22029/com.healthchat.healthchat D/Pushwoosh: [RequestManager] setBadge response success
>   02-22 18:01:40.523 22004-22029/com.healthchat.healthchat D/Pushwoosh: [RequestManager] Try To send: setBadge
>   02-22 18:01:40.842 22004-22029/com.healthchat.healthchat I/Pushwoosh: [RequestManager] 
>                                                                         x
>                                                                         |     Pushwoosh request:
>                                                                         | 
>                                                                         | Payload: {"request":{"v":"4.1.5","application":"DBCD2-4E3E5","badge":12,"hwid":"75e1bbb1ee4980df","device_type":3,"userId":"75e1bbb1ee4980df"}}
>                                                                         | Response: {"status_code":200,"status_message":"OK","response":null}
>                                                                         x
>   02-22 18:01:40.843 22004-22029/com.healthchat.healthchat D/Pushwoosh: [RequestManager] setBadge response success
>   02-22 18:01:41.844 22004-22029/com.healthchat.healthchat D/Pushwoosh: [RequestManager] Try To send: setBadge
>   02-22 18:01:42.049 22004-22029/com.healthchat.healthchat I/Pushwoosh: [RequestManager] 
>                                                                         x
>                                                                         |     Pushwoosh request:
>                                                                         | 
>                                                                         | Payload: {"request":{"v":"4.1.5","application":"DBCD2-4E3E5","badge":12,"hwid":"75e1bbb1ee4980df","device_type":3,"userId":"75e1bbb1ee4980df"}}
>                                                                         | Response: {"status_code":200,"status_message":"OK","response":null}
>                                                                         x
>   02-22 18:01:42.050 22004-22029/com.healthchat.healthchat D/Pushwoosh: [RequestManager] setBadge response success
>   02-22 18:01:45.306 22004-22004/com.healthchat.healthchat I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(25)] "No Content-Security-Policy meta tag found. Please add one when using the cordova-plugin-whitelist plugin.", source: file:///android_asset/framework_assets/plugins/cordova-plugin-whitelist/whitelist.js (25)
>   02-22 18:01:55.307 22004-22004/com.healthchat.healthchat I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(25)] "No Content-Security-Policy meta tag found. Please add one when using the cordova-plugin-whitelist plugin.", source: file:///android_asset/framework_assets/plugins/cordova-plugin-whitelist/whitelist.js (25)
>   02-22 18:02:05.306 22004-22004/com.healthchat.healthchat I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(25)] "No Content-Security-Policy meta tag found. Please add one when using the cordova-plugin-whitelist plugin.", source: file:///android_asset/framework_assets/plugins/cordova-plugin-whitelist/whitelist.js (25)
>   02-22 18:02:15.307 22004-22004/com.healthchat.healthchat I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(25)] "No Content-Security-Policy meta tag found. Please add one when using the cordova-plugin-whitelist plugin.", source: file:///android_asset/framework_assets/plugins/cordova-plugin-whitelist/whitelist.js (25)
>   02-22 18:02:25.311 22004-22004/com.healthchat.healthchat I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(25)] "No Content-Security-Policy meta tag found. Please add one when using the cordova-plugin-whitelist plugin.", source: file:///android_asset/framework_assets/plugins/cordova-plugin-whitelist/whitelist.js (25)
>   02-22 18:02:35.309 22004-22004/com.healthchat.healthchat I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(25)] "No Content-Security-Policy meta tag found. Please add one when using the cordova-plugin-whitelist plugin.", source: file:///android_asset/framework_assets/plugins/cordova-plugin-whitelist/whitelist.js (25)
>   02-22 18:02:45.309 22004-22004/com.healthchat.healthchat I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(25)] "No Content-Security-Policy meta tag found. Please add one when using the cordova-plugin-whitelist plugin.", source: file:///android_asset/framework_assets/plugins/cordova-plugin-whitelist/whitelist.js (25)
>   02-22 18:02:55.307 22004-22004/com.healthchat.healthchat I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(25)] "No Content-Security-Policy meta tag found. Please add one when using the cordova-plugin-whitelist plugin.", source: file:///android_asset/framework_assets/plugins/cordova-plugin-whitelist/whitelist.js (25)
>   02-22 18:03:05.306 22004-22004/com.healthchat.healthchat I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(25)] "No Content-Security-Policy meta tag found. Please add one when using the cordova-plugin-whitelist plugin.", source: file:///android_asset/framework_assets/plugins/cordova-plugin-whitelist/whitelist.js (25)
>   02-22 18:03:15.307 22004-22004/com.healthchat.healthchat I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(25)] "No Content-Security-Policy meta tag found. Please add one when using the cordova-plugin-whitelist plugin.", source: file:///android_asset/framework_assets/plugins/cordova-plugin-whitelist/whitelist.js (25)
>   02-22 18:03:25.312 22004-22004/com.healthchat.healthchat I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(25)] "No Content-Security-Policy meta tag found. Please add one when using the cordova-plugin-whitelist plugin.", source: file:///android_asset/framework_assets/plugins/cordova-plugin-whitelist/whitelist.js (25)
>   02-22 18:03:35.314 22004-22004/com.healthchat.healthchat I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(25)] "No Content-Security-Policy meta tag found. Please add one when using the cordova-plugin-whitelist plugin.", source: file:///android_asset/framework_assets/plugins/cordova-plugin-whitelist/whitelist.js (25)
>   02-22 18:03:45.307 22004-22004/com.healthchat.healthchat I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(25)] "No Content-Security-Policy meta tag found. Please add one when using the cordova-plugin-whitelist plugin.", source: file:///android_asset/framework_assets/plugins/cordova-plugin-whitelist/whitelist.js (25)
>   02-22 18:03:55.306 22004-22004/com.healthchat.healthchat I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(25)] "No Content-Security-Policy meta tag found. Please add one when using the cordova-plugin-whitelist plugin.", source: file:///android_asset/framework_assets/plugins/cordova-plugin-whitelist/whitelist.js (25)
>   02-22 18:04:05.306 22004-22004/com.healthchat.healthchat I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(25)] "No Content-Security-Policy meta tag found. Please add one when using the cordova-plugin-whitelist plugin.", source: file:///android_asset/framework_assets/plugins/cordova-plugin-whitelist/whitelist.js (25)
>   02-22 18:04:15.307 22004-22004/com.healthchat.healthchat I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(25)] "No Content-Security-Policy meta tag found. Please add one when using the cordova-plugin-whitelist plugin.", source: file:///android_asset/framework_assets/plugins/cordova-plugin-whitelist/whitelist.js (25)
>   02-22 18:04:25.306 22004-22004/com.healthchat.healthchat I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(25)] "No Content-Security-Policy meta tag found. Please add one when using the cordova-plugin-whitelist plugin.", source: file:///android_asset/framework_assets/plugins/cordova-plugin-whitelist/whitelist.js (25)
>   02-22 18:04:35.307 22004-22004/com.healthchat.healthchat I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(25)] "No Content-Security-Policy meta tag found. Please add one when using the cordova-plugin-whitelist plugin.", source: file:///android_asset/framework_assets/plugins/cordova-plugin-whitelist/whitelist.js (25)
>   02-22 18:04:45.306 22004-22004/com.healthchat.healthchat I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(25)] "No Content-Security-Policy meta tag found. Please add one when using the cordova-plugin-whitelist plugin.", source: file:///android_asset/framework_assets/plugins/cordova-plugin-whitelist/whitelist.js (25)
>   02-22 18:04:55.308 22004-22004/com.healthchat.healthchat I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(25)] "No Content-Security-Policy meta tag found. Please add one when using the cordova-plugin-whitelist plugin.", source: file:///android_asset/framework_assets/plugins/cordova-plugin-whitelist/whitelist.js (25)

HERE IS WHEN THE ACTIVITY IS RELAUNCHED

> 02-22 18:05:00.210 22004-22004/com.healthchat.healthchat I/TEST HC: activities size after unregister = 1
>   02-22 18:05:00.210 22004-22004/com.healthchat.healthchat W/>> OpenTOK >>: >>>>>>>> RELEASE CAMERA
>   02-22 18:05:00.376 22004-22004/com.healthchat.healthchat W/{{{{ CVD OVERRIDE }}}: On destroy!!!!!
>   02-22 18:05:00.376 22004-22004/com.healthchat.healthchat W/{{{{ CVD OVERRIDE }}}: TRACE!!!!!: 
>   02-22 18:05:00.378 22004-22004/com.healthchat.healthchat D/cr_Ime: [InputMethodManagerWrapper.java:59] isActive: true
>   02-22 18:05:00.379 22004-22004/com.healthchat.healthchat D/cr_Ime: [InputMethodManagerWrapper.java:68] hideSoftInputFromWindow
>   02-22 18:05:00.409 22004-22004/com.healthchat.healthchat D/cr_Ime: [InputMethodManagerWrapper.java:59] isActive: true
>   02-22 18:05:00.410 22004-22004/com.healthchat.healthchat D/cr_Ime: [InputMethodManagerWrapper.java:68] hideSoftInputFromWindow
>   02-22 18:05:00.410 22004-22004/com.healthchat.healthchat W/cr_ScreenOrientation: Removing an inexistent observer!
>   02-22 18:05:00.410 22004-22004/com.healthchat.healthchat E/chromium: [ERROR:runtime_javascript_dialog_manager.cc(73)] Not implemented reached in virtual void xwalk::RuntimeJavaScriptDialogManager::ResetDialogState(content::WebContents*)
>   02-22 18:05:00.417 22004-22004/com.healthchat.healthchat I/OTPlugin: Destroying plugin
>   02-22 18:05:00.417 22004-22004/com.healthchat.healthchat I/opentok-session: Disconnecting to the session
>   02-22 18:05:00.418 22004-22389/com.healthchat.healthchat I/opentok-session: Session connection is dropped. ConnectionId: 8b0ee595-a97a-48c4-8538-6404ef7e92b7
>   02-22 18:05:00.451 22004-22004/com.healthchat.healthchat W/{{{{ CVD OVERRIDE }}}: On create!!!!!
>   02-22 18:05:00.451 22004-22004/com.healthchat.healthchat W/{{{{ CVD OVERRIDE }}}: Load config
>   02-22 18:05:00.451 22004-22004/com.healthchat.healthchat W/{{{{ CVD OVERRIDE }}}: Parse
>   02-22 18:05:00.452 22004-22004/com.healthchat.healthchat W/{{{{ CVD OVERRIDE }}}: Fuera: healthchat.healthchat.com.healthchatapi
>   02-22 18:05:00.452 22004-22004/com.healthchat.healthchat W/{{{{ CVD OVERRIDE }}}: Entroooooo: com.healthchat.healthchat
>   02-22 18:05:00.473 22004-22004/com.healthchat.healthchat W/{{{{ CVD OVERRIDE }}}: Plugins: [org.apache.cordova.PluginEntry@428fe1e0, org.apache.cordova.PluginEntry@428fe2e0, org.apache.cordova.PluginEntry@428fe510, org.apache.cordova.PluginEntry@428fe5e8, org.apache.cordova.PluginEntry@428fe710, org.apache.cordova.PluginEntry@428fe810, org.apache.cordova.PluginEntry@428fe8f0, org.apache.cordova.PluginEntry@428fe9d8, org.apache.cordova.PluginEntry@428feac0, org.apache.cordova.PluginEntry@428febc8, org.apache.cordova.PluginEntry@428fecc0]
>   02-22 18:05:00.486 22004-22004/com.healthchat.healthchat D/XWalkContent: CompositingSurfaceType is SurfaceView
>   02-22 18:05:00.489 22004-22004/com.healthchat.healthchat D/cr_Ime: [InputMethodManagerWrapper.java:30] Constructor
>   02-22 18:05:00.511 22004-22389/com.healthchat.healthchat I/opentok-session: Session is disconnected
>   02-22 18:05:00.512 22004-25683/com.healthchat.healthchat I/QCNEA   : |NIMS|: getaddrinfo: hostname hlg.tokbox.com servname 443 numeric 0 appname /system/bin/app_process
>   02-22 18:05:00.541 22004-22004/com.healthchat.healthchat W/TEST DELETE: Starting deleting videos....
>   02-22 18:05:00.541 22004-22004/com.healthchat.healthchat W/TEST DELETE: List of videos: []
>   02-22 18:05:00.541 22004-22004/com.healthchat.healthchat W/TEST DELETE: Before emptying urls file.
>   02-22 18:05:00.541 22004-22004/com.healthchat.healthchat W/TEST DELETE: Starting emptying urls file....
>   02-22 18:05:00.542 22004-22004/com.healthchat.healthchat W/TEST DELETE: Urls file EMPTY
>   02-22 18:05:00.546 22004-22004/com.healthchat.healthchat D/XWalkActivity: Activate by XWalkActivity
>   02-22 18:05:00.546 22004-22004/com.healthchat.healthchat D/XWalkLib: ActivateTask started
>   02-22 18:05:00.547 22004-22004/com.healthchat.healthchat I/TEST HC: activities size after register = 2
>   02-22 18:05:00.548 22004-22004/com.healthchat.healthchat W/>> OpenTOK >>: >>>>>>>> RESUME CAMERA
>   02-22 18:05:00.771 22004-22004/com.healthchat.healthchat D/Camera: app passed NULL surface
>   02-22 18:05:00.819 22004-22004/com.healthchat.healthchat I/OTPlugin: connection dropped: 8b0ee595-a97a-48c4-8538-6404ef7e92b7
>   02-22 18:05:00.831 22004-22004/com.healthchat.healthchat D/XWalkLib: ActivateTask finished, -1
>   02-22 18:05:00.842 22004-22004/com.healthchat.healthchat I/cr_Ime: ImeThread is not enabled.
>   02-22 18:05:00.878 22004-22204/com.healthchat.healthchat E/Adreno-ES20: : Invalid texture format! Returning error!
>   02-22 18:05:00.878 22004-22204/com.healthchat.healthchat E/Adreno-ES20: : Framebuffer color attachment incomplete. Returning GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT!
>   02-22 18:05:00.882 22004-22004/com.healthchat.healthchat E/chromium: [ERROR:layer_tree_host_impl.cc(2218)] Forcing zero-copy tile initialization as worker context is missing
>   02-22 18:05:00.927 22004-22004/com.healthchat.healthchat W/cr_BindingManager: Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 22004
>   02-22 18:05:00.929 22004-22004/com.healthchat.healthchat D/cr_Ime: [InputMethodManagerWrapper.java:59] isActive: true
>   02-22 18:05:00.929 22004-22004/com.healthchat.healthchat D/cr_Ime: [InputMethodManagerWrapper.java:68] hideSoftInputFromWindow
>   02-22 18:05:01.345 22004-22004/com.healthchat.healthchat D/JsMessageQueue: Set native->JS mode to OnlineEventsBridgeMode
>   02-22 18:05:01.526 22004-22004/com.healthchat.healthchat I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(23)] "No Content-Security-Policy meta tag found. Please add one when using the cordova-plugin-whitelist plugin.", source: file:///android_asset/framework_assets/plugins/cordova-plugin-whitelist/whitelist.js (23)
>   02-22 18:05:04.890 22004-22004/com.healthchat.healthchat I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "includeeee", source: file:///android_asset/framework_assets/app.js (1)
>   02-22 18:05:05.726 22004-22004/com.healthchat.healthchat E/Camera: Error 5001
>   02-22 18:05:05.770 22004-22241/com.healthchat.healthchat D/PluginManager: exec() call to unknown plugin: Insomnia
>   02-22 18:05:05.776 22004-22241/com.healthchat.healthchat D/NativeAudio: Plugin Called: preloadComplex
>   02-22 18:05:05.910 22004-22004/com.healthchat.healthchat I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "error: A reference already exists for the specified audio id.", source: file:///android_asset/framework_assets/app.js (1)
>   02-22 18:05:05.910 22004-22004/com.healthchat.healthchat I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "showLogin", source: file:///android_asset/framework_assets/app.js (1)
>   02-22 18:05:05.914 22004-22204/com.healthchat.healthchat E/Adreno-ES20: : Invalid texture format! Returning error!
>   02-22 18:05:05.914 22004-22204/com.healthchat.healthchat E/Adreno-ES20: : Framebuffer color attachment incomplete. Returning GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT!
>   02-22 18:05:05.918 22004-22004/com.healthchat.healthchat E/chromium: [ERROR:layer_tree_host_impl.cc(2218)] Forcing zero-copy tile initialization as worker context is missing
>   02-22 18:05:06.131 22004-22438/com.healthchat.healthchat I/QCNEA   : |NIMS|: getaddrinfo: hostname mia01.carvajalonline.com servname NULL numeric 0 appname /system/bin/app_process
>   02-22 18:05:06.553 22004-22004/com.healthchat.healthchat I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "sessionId", source: file:///android_asset/framework_assets/app.js (1)
>   02-22 18:05:06.554 22004-22004/com.healthchat.healthchat I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "result now", source: file:///android_asset/framework_assets/app.js (1)
>   02-22 18:05:07.140 22004-22004/com.healthchat.healthchat I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "status", source: file:///android_asset/framework_assets/app.js (1)
>   02-22 18:05:07.269 22004-22004/com.healthchat.healthchat I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(752)] "tbsession this", source: file:///android_asset/framework_assets/plugins/com.tokbox.cordova.opentok/www/opentok.js (752)
>   02-22 18:05:07.276 22004-22241/com.healthchat.healthchat D/OTPlugin: Initialize Plugin
>   02-22 18:05:07.276 22004-22241/com.healthchat.healthchat I/OTPlugin: initSession
>   02-22 18:05:07.276 22004-22241/com.healthchat.healthchat E/OTPlugin: Failed to set parent background to WHITE
>   02-22 18:05:07.277 22004-22241/com.healthchat.healthchat I/OTPlugin: created new session with data: ["45700062","2_MX40NTcwMDA2Mn5-MTQ3NjIxMjgzMzkyOX5OMGJYWWhmU1JuaU1iaUVoVEw4Tk5FUnV-fg"]
>   02-22 18:05:07.279 22004-22241/com.healthchat.healthchat D/opentok-session: HW decoding enabled? : false
>   02-22 18:05:07.323 22004-22241/com.healthchat.healthchat W/PluginManager: THREAD WARNING: exec() call to OpenTokPlugin.initSession blocked the main thread for 47ms. Plugin should use CordovaInterface.getThreadPool().
>   02-22 18:05:07.344 22004-22241/com.healthchat.healthchat I/OTPlugin: addEvent
>   02-22 18:05:07.344 22004-22241/com.healthchat.healthchat I/OTPlugin: adding new event - sessionEvents
>   02-22 18:05:07.345 22004-22241/com.healthchat.healthchat I/OTPlugin: connect
>   02-22 18:05:07.346 22004-22241/com.healthchat.healthchat I/OTPlugin: connect command called
>   02-22 18:05:07.346 22004-22241/com.healthchat.healthchat I/opentok-session: Connecting to the session. SessionID: 2_MX40NTcwMDA2Mn5-MTQ3NjIxMjgzMzkyOX5OMGJYWWhmU1JuaU1iaUVoVEw4Tk5FUnV-fg Token: T1==cGFydG5lcl9pZD00NTcwMDA2MiZzaWc9NjM5YjZjOWRiMDdmMjI0NjZjMjUxZTZkMTk4YjY4N2M4ZTMxOGNmNzpzZXNzaW9uX2lkPTJfTVg0ME5UY3dNREEyTW41LU1UUTNOakl4TWpnek16a3lPWDVPTUdKWVdXaG1VMUp1YVUxaWFVVm9WRXc0VGs1RlVuVi1mZyZjcmVhdGVfdGltZT0xNDg3ODA1MDIwJm5vbmNlPS0xNzUxNTgxNTYxJnJvbGU9cHVibGlzaGVyJmV4cGlyZV90aW1lPTE0ODc4OTE0MjAmY29ubmVjdGlvbl9kYXRhPTE0OTUx ApiKey: 45700062
>   02-22 18:05:07.407 22004-25948/com.healthchat.healthchat I/QCNEA   : |NIMS|: getaddrinfo: hostname hlg.tokbox.com servname 443 numeric 0 appname /system/bin/app_process
>   02-22 18:05:07.467 22004-25954/com.healthchat.healthchat I/QCNEA   : |NIMS|: getaddrinfo: hostname hlg.tokbox.com servname 443 numeric 0 appname /system/bin/app_process
>   02-22 18:05:07.503 22004-22241/com.healthchat.healthchat W/PluginManager: THREAD WARNING: exec() call to OpenTokPlugin.connect blocked the main thread for 157ms. Plugin should use CordovaInterface.getThreadPool().
>   02-22 18:05:07.512 22004-25956/com.healthchat.healthchat I/QCNEA   : |NIMS|: getaddrinfo: hostname anvil.opentok.com servname 443 numeric 0 appname /system/bin/app_process
>   02-22 18:05:08.186 22004-25968/com.healthchat.healthchat I/QCNEA   : |NIMS|: getaddrinfo: hostname mantis002-dal.tokbox.com servname 443 numeric 0 appname /system/bin/app_process
>   02-22 18:05:08.880 22004-25994/com.healthchat.healthchat I/QCNEA   : |NIMS|: getaddrinfo: hostname hlg.tokbox.com servname 443 numeric 0 appname /system/bin/app_process
>   02-22 18:05:08.924 22004-22389/com.healthchat.healthchat I/opentok-session: Session is connected

Comment: This can have many reasons. It would be best to connect to the android device with adb  and collect the logs when the crash is happening. `adb logcat`The logs will then show you what exactly goes wrong.

Comment: @MichaelB please see my edit.